# Core Data naming convention for attribute accessors in NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm currently writing an `NSManagedObject` and am looking for naming convention ideas. Here's my code:

```swift
final class StrokeSample: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged private var location: String
    var _location: CGPoint {
        get {
            return NSCoder.cgPoint(for: location)
        }
        set  {
            location = NSCoder.string(for: newValue)
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have a `CGPoint` object that is stored into Core Data as a `String`. The issue I have here, is how should I name those two variables that describe the exact same property in an elegant way?

What I've already considered:

1. In my `xcdatamodel` object, naming the attributes `string[PropertyName]`. **Pros:** resolves the ambiguity of, for example, having a property named `rect` that is described as `String` in the data model. Also, outside the data model, everything is very clear. **Cons:** Writing *string* before every attribute looks messy in the model.
2. Putting a `_` before the computed properties' names in my `NSManagedObject`. This is what is highlighted in my example. **Pros:** This leaves the `xcdatamodel` clean. **Cons:** forces me to use underscores everywhere in my Swift code.
3. Putting a `_` before the attribute name in the Data Model. Xcode prevents it.

[image: Xcode: name must begin with a letter]

I think option *1* is the better one since the mess is restricted at only one place. But if you have better ideas on this particular issue, they are welcome. Thank you

Comment: Why you don't autogenerate the properties?

Comment: I don't think auto-generation could solve this particular issue. Can it? 
Apart from that, this is my first time using Core Data and I'm trying to get a good grasp on the subject. So I avoid auto-generation for now.

Comment: Okay, well anyway your way is the way everyone is doing it I think. You should reverse the underscore: the private property needs to have the underscore and the internal/public property not. But this is opinion based.

Comment: Please follow the advice of @J.Doe regarding underscores.  It is more than just an opinion.  Auto-generated properties have used this convention in Objective-C for ten years.  It is a world-wide concensus.

Comment: Alright, so I intended to kind of follow it by naming my attributes `string[AttributeName]`. But if you tell me that it's ok to put underscores in the data model then that's what I'm going to do. Thank you very much! 

**EDIT**: That doesn't work. Attributes in the data model must start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

The convention seems to be to put an underscore after a property name when you want to make it "private" as in the data model it must start with a letter.